# Using TypeScript with proprietary properties for HTML5 iOS apps

Tags: android, ios, html, webkit, typescript

Does anyone have a working example of using *proprietary properties* like *"ontouchend"*, and *"gestureend"* in **TypeScript**?

I've tried using something like this below:

```
//Create an alert.
function TouchedScreen(username: string): void  {
    alert(username + " has touched the screen.");
}

//Touch anywhere on screen for an alert on iOS/Android
window.ontouchend = () => {
    TouchedScreen("[username]");
};
```

I'm assuming this is due to ontouchend being a proprietary property, using addEventListener compiles correctly but I wan't to use it with a property, how can I do this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell typescript that these properties exist on `Window`:

```
interface Window{
    ontouchend: Function;   
}

//Touch anywhere on screen for an alert on iOS/Android
window.ontouchend = () => { // compiles fine   
};
```

If you want the same event on *all* `HTMLElement`s just tell TypeScript about that too:

```
interface HTMLElement {
    ontouchend: Function;
}

var a: HTMLAnchorElement;
a.ontouchend = () => { // compiles fine   
};
```

Comment: Awesome, that solves the question, but how would you incorporate that for every DOM element without typing every element with it's own interface?